# How does Windows programming vary from Unix programing

Tags: .net, windows, macos, cocoa, api

If not an expert programer I am at least familiar with the basic steps required to program from OS X or Linux, I have no experience on a Windows system however. My work is mainly focussed around security applications.

What makes programing on Windows different?

To be clear I am not looking for a debate, only a list I could then use as a starting place to fill in the gaps of my knowledge.

Comment: You would probably have more joy googling this and then asking any specific questions that rise up.

Comment: no and from what I hear there is not really a reason to. Thanks for the info though - really great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely, one can state that 
Windows has its own functions - methods, if you deal with OOP - 
which can make possible your program to interact with the underlying 
Windows OS.

For example, if you want to create a new process which runs in the security 
context of a specific user, you can call the `CreateProcessAsUser`
function.

In general, Windows own functions are richer than the respective Unix 
flavors. Besides in Windows you have usually more than one or two ways to 
get your jobs done.

Comment: More than 1, or 2, and each fraught with danger... Each high level and specialized and doesn't do what you think it will